# Prefix sum time complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am reading [this](http://codility.com/media/train/3-PrefixSums.pdf), the exercise in the last part.

I am new to time  complexity.

First solution says the robot would move `p` times in one direction and then `m - p` in the other direction, for `p` from `0` to `m`, to me this is:

```
sums = []
for left in 0..m
  sums[left] = 0
  for right in 0..(m-left)
    sums[left] += A[k - left + right] || 0
    A[k - left + right] = 0
```

`A` is the input array, `k` is an initial position, i.e. a given constant.

From what I understand complexity would be:

```
O(m + m+(m-1)+(m-2)+...+3+2+1)
  |   -----------------------
  |               |
  because        because the inner loop
  first loop

O(m + (m*(m+1))/2)
O(m + (m*(m+1))/2)
O(m^2) ?
```

What is my error here?

Solution for this problem states that complexity is `O(n*m)`, can you explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

```
the goal is to calculate the maximum sum that the robot can collect in m moves.
```

With that, I understand the algorithm will be something like:

```
max=0;
for i in 1..n
    for j in 1..m
        sum+=A[i]
    end loop;
    if sum>max then 
        max=sum;
    end if;
    sum=0;
end loop;
```

That it's an O(n*m) problem (if I understand correctly the problem)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention `k` I updated problem, robot starts in position `k` and moves just `m` times, I am not able to understand why `n` is involved, could you explain?